# factory girl uniqueness validation fails for associated factories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, factory-bot

I have (simplified) factories defined as follows:

```
factory :league do
  acronym 'NBA'
end

factory :division do
  league
end
```

Divisions belong to Leagues. When I define this factory, it was my assumption that 1 league would be created, and that league would be reused over and over again to give divisions a real league_id.

Instead, I'm getting errors on the 2nd call of `FactoryGirl.create(:division)` because the League `acronym` is supposed to be unique.

```
class League < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :acronym, uniqueness: true
end
```

leading to the following break in the test

> ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Acronym has already been taken

How can I work around this, preferably without creating a hierarchy in the setup to the test?

If theres something better than factory_girl for what I'm trying to accomplish, please do suggest it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `initialize_with` in your league definition.

See http://robots.thoughtbot.com/post/16196616388/factory-girl-2-5-gets-custom-constructors

You could then issue `find_or_create_by_acronym` to guarantee it's created once.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on where you're calling FactoryGirl.create the records will get created for every spec you have. What you want is [`database_cleaner`](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner), once set up, it will clean up your database after every spec making sure your validation errors are no longer an issue.

**EDIT**

Whoops, I misread your question. What you'll want to do is either use the `faker` gem to generate random strings for each acronym or use `factory_girl` sequence like this

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  sequence :acronym do |n|
    "NBA#{n}"
  end

  factory :league do
    acronym
  end
end
```

Using sequence will actually make sure that every league created has a unique acronym.